# Yii2: How create an route to common

Tags: php, yii2

I want create an "errorAction" in "common". So that when a page does not exist, be redirected to action "index" in "common/controllers/ErrorController".

I have this:

> common\main.php

```
<?php
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'error/index',
        ],
    ],
];
```

And this structure:

```
common
 - controllers
 - - ErrorController.php
 - views
 - - error
 - - - index.php
```

But I want it to redirect there even when there is no "frontend" folder on the server (it does not exist temporarily because of maintenance).

I use the extension "Yii2 Maintenance mode component", and it redirects correctly to the view I created in the "common" folder.
The problem is that when I have deleted both the "backend" and "frontend" folder from the server, it does not redirect to the maintenance page, and it shows the default page of the Apache "404 Not Found".

> common\main-local.php

```
...
        'maintenanceMode' => [
            'class' => 'brussens\maintenance\MaintenanceMode',
            'layoutPath' => '@common/views/layouts/maintenance',
            'viewPath' => '@common/views/maintenance/index',
            'roles' => [
                'administrator',
            ],
            'urls' => [
                'site/login',
            ],
        ],
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this adding a `.htaccess` file in your document root. With this configuration you have been redirected on `common` page when a folder/file not exist instead of a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . route/to/your/common/handler [L]
```